# elementor plugin - content disappeared, blank page

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Hoping someone else out there has maybe run into this issue and might have some insight.   We’re using the latest versions of wp and elementor. Elementor pages, seemingly at random, are being completely erased when saved. We go from a page full of formatted content to a blank page template. Trying to use the revisions tool in wp gets some content back but all elementor formatting is gone and elementor's built in revisions tool has nothing to roll back to.  Afraid to do any more work on the site and we were very close to launching.  Thanks, Rich

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you asked the plugin author? You are likely to get better support there....